# What it's like walking a beagle dog, or

Tags: sentence-construction

Which of these two sentences, if any, are correct?

(I want to use the correct sentence as an introduction for a video, a video explaining my experience taking a beagle dog for a walk.)

1. What it's like to walk a beagle dog.
2. What it's like walking a beagle dog.

Comment: We usually call them "beagles," not "beagle dogs."

Comment: *Walking my beagle*

Answer (score 1):

Both constructions are correct and mean the same.  I prefer the infinitive "to walk" (for reasons of style that I can't rationally explain, it just scans better)

Note. The name of the breed is the "beagle", you don't need to say "beagle dog".

Answer (score 0):

Either is acceptable as a video title. Note that neither one is a complete sentence.